# Collision in java not detecting fast enough in a grid based collision system

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using a 2d boolean array for my collision between true spots in java libgdx. My collision checks and sees if the player can or can't move left or right or fall or jump. This all works however the collision is not fast enough to detect when the player should lets say stop falling. The player is pretty much 1/5 the way inside the platform by the time he stops.

Here is an image to describe better what I mean. The player is in pink the collidable platforms are in red. The following image is of the player just landing from a small drop onto the platform and very very slow gravity.

[image: Player collision]

My collision class is pretty straight forward, if the current position is already true don't allow movement, here is the class just for a reference. Note the class is fully functional, just slow.

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    if(mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) (entity.getGridPosition().x + 1)][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y + 1]){
        entity.setCanMoveRight(false);
    }else
        entity.setCanMoveRight(true);

    if(mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) (entity.getGridPosition().x - 1)][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y + 1]){
        entity.setCanMoveLeft(false);
    }else
        entity.setCanMoveLeft(true);



    if(mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) (entity.getGridPosition().x)][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y] ||
            (mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) (entity.getGridPosition().x + 1)][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y] &&
                    !mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) (entity.getGridPosition().x)][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y])){
        entity.setCanFall(false);
    }else
        entity.setCanFall(true);



}
```

and here is where everything is being updated.

```
    @Override
public void render () {
    collisionHandler.run();
    player.update();
    mapGrid.update();

    tmpLogger.log();
    camera.position.set(player.getPosition(), 0);
    camera.translate(player.getPosition());
    camera.update();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    tmpRend.begin();
    mapGrid.render(tmpRend);
    player.render(tmpRend);
    tmpRend.end();
}
```

I have looked for hours and hours and I can't seem to get the player where I want him. Just for reference here is what I want the player to look like after his small drop, or any drop of any speed.
[image]

Any help at all is extremely appreciated. I just need my collision to be very accurate, not sort of accurate. Thank you!!

Comment: I'm not sure of the libgdx but this really shouldn't happen. Are you updating the pos of the player before checking for collisions?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils if you look at the second segment of code you'll see that I am indeed updating the collision first then the player. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: i am wondering if you really move it slow because if you move it fast it's  common problem because you update only max. 60times per second. So if it moves fast it could be "over the edge" because you notice it to late. A solution for this would be to outsource the update into a other thread which has a higher updaterate. (e.g. 120 fps per nyquist theorem)

Comment: This appears far too simple to not be able to handle collisions with this problem or the need of another thread. You should update the player, check for collisions per the new location of the player, resolve it, then render it. The reason is because if you pushed a direction, the player doesn't move until it's updated and rendered; then you see it. But if you check for a collision *before* updating then you'll miss your first opportunity to resolve the collision and render the player inside the other object. In my experience anyway.

Comment: @BennX I can assure you it is moving very slow, the velocity downward is at 0.0081 and it takes a 7 seconds to hit that spot from just one block above

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I did what you said and received the exact same product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it it is never good enough just to stop the avatar after collision; in real life a slightly slow frame can then embed you avatar in the surface (as you are experiencing) - you need to detect the point of collision and then move the avatar **only** that far so that it **just sits** on the collision point.

Another way of saying this is that when you detect a collision with the ground you need to move the avatar back up so that it is just above the ground.

Comment: Thank you I took what you said and gave my character and exact position to stop instead of a grid position and it worked. As well as reducing the amount of Booleans for collision detection, anyway thank you.